# Create a Multidimensional Array and json_encode

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, mysqli

I have to get a JSON response from the database:

id and last_active:

```
$users = array();

$stmt = $mysqli->query('SELECT id, last_active FROM users WHERE status = 1');
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    $users[]['id'] = $row['id'];
    $users[]['last_active'] = $row['last_active'];
}

echo json_encode($users);
```

The array must be as follows:

```
$users = array (
  0 => array(1, 1522921015),
  1 => array(2, 1522921019),
  2 => array(3, 1522921102),
  3 => array(4, 1522921195),
  4 => array(5, 1522921034)
);
```

How to properly build the multidimensional array with the query result?

Comment: And what exactly is the problem with the code you have?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
  $users = array();

  $stmt = $mysqli->query('SELECT id, last_active FROM users WHERE status = 1');
  $i=0;
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    $users[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
    $users[$i]['last_active'] = $row['last_active'];
    $i++;
  }

    echo json_encode($users);
```

Comment: This would give the same result as OP's current code

Answer (score 1):

You can use temporary array like this:

```
$users = array();

$stmt = $mysqli->query('SELECT id, last_active FROM users WHERE status = 1');
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    $tempArray = []; // added
    $tempArray[] = $row['id'];
    $tempArray[] = $row['last_active'];
    $users[] = $tempArray; // added
}

echo json_encode($users);
```

or directly assign both values :

```
$users[] = array($row['id'],$row['last_active']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove json_encode just print $user

Answer (score 0):

You should push an array without keys to get the expected data:

```
$users = array();
$stmt = $mysqli->query('SELECT id, last_active FROM users WHERE status = 1');
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    $users[] = [ $row['id'], $row['last_active'] ];
}
```

So, `$users` will be equals to:

```
$users = array (
  0 => array(1, 1522921015),
  1 => array(2, 1522921019),
  2 => array(3, 1522921102),
  3 => array(4, 1522921195),
  4 => array(5, 1522921034)
);
```

Or, using the `MYSQLI_NUM` options with [`fetch_array()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php):

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    $users[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

my choise will be like this:

```
$users = array();

$stmt = $mysqli->query('SELECT id, last_active FROM users WHERE status = 1');
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
      $users[] = [
          $row['id'],
          $row['last_active'],
     ];
}

echo json_encode($users);
```